# Переместить данные из Vector <Float> в float[] (Android)

Tags: java, android, vector, float

Мне нужно переместить данные из Vector  в float[]. Как это сделать? Я написал вот такой вариант, но он долгий... Подскажите готовый вариант если есть.

```
private void convert_Float_To_float_data(float out[], Vector <Float> in)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++)
    {
        out[i] = in.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: В каком смысле долгий? Работает долго?

Comment: Да. Долговато. Но так как другого решения нет, то вопрос закрыт

Comment: а вам точно `Vector` нужен? `ArrayList` может побыстрее работать. `Vector` вообще как бы устарел и не рекомендуется к использованию. Ну и вообще тот, кто изначально создаёт этот самый вектор, мог бы создавать массив `float[]`. Тогда бы и преобразовывать не надо было.

Comment: @CJ1: долго он работает в первую очередь из-за устаревшего `Vector`. Рекомендую использовать ответ Tagir, он надежнее, т.к. сам создает массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартного метода для преобразования boxed-значений в примитивный массив в Java нет. Ваш способ нормальный, хотя я бы создавал новый массив и сделал поддержку любых входных коллекций:

```
static float[] toPrimitiveFloat(Collection<Float> in) {
    float[] result = new float[in.size()];
    int i=0;
    for(Float val : in) {
        result[i++] = val;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Подобный метод есть, например, в библиотеке Apache Common Lang: [`ArrayUtils.toPrimitive()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Float[]%29). Только он преобразует не коллекцию, а массив. [Внутри там](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.java#ArrayUtils.toPrimitive%28java.lang.Float[]%29) аналогичный цикл. Проще никак.

Comment: Можно ли надеяться на ускорение, если писать в несколько потоков?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, можно надеяться, но уверены ли вы, что это самое узкое место в программе? :-) Насколько я понимаю, тормозить может из-за того, что в андроиде туповатая JVM (я под андроид не пишу). На Hotspot это очень быстрый код, который выиграет разве что при очень огромных массивах (тогда в Java-8 можно сделать `IntStream.range(0, in.size()).parallelStream().forEach(i -> result[i] = in.get(i));`). Ну и я на самом деле не очень уверен, что у автора это самое узкое место. Неизвестно ведь, как он профилировал код.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public Float[] convertVector(Vector<Float> foo)
{ 
    return foo.toArray(new Float[0]);
}
```

Comment: У вас массив `Float`, а не `float`. А еще, почему массив нулевой длины? Разве войдет в него содержимое вектора?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если передать массив нулевой длины, `toArray()` его проигнорирует и создаст новый массив нужной длины. Работать будет, только лишний объект сборщику мусора подбирать. А про `float` замечание верное.

Comment: @TagirValeev: т.е всё это ещё можно обернуть в `if (true) {...}`? )

Comment: Да, все верно, но автор попросил другой способ, а это наверное один из немногих "других" способов. А с массивом Float можно работать так же как и смасивом float.